# Silverstripe 3.1 - onBefore/After Delete/Write doesn't work

Tags: silverstripe

I'm trying to execute a simple write command on onAfterWrite or before or onBeforeDelete. But it simply doesn't work.

Object1 -> here I want to execute the code. Has a $has_one relation(Item) to the Object2

```
public function onAfterWrite(){
    parent::onAfterWrite();

    $item = Object2::get()->byID($this->ItemID);
    $item->Title = 'test123';
    $item->write();
}
```

The same problem in each other onAfter/Before function.
If got no error, or anything else.

Where could the mistake be?

Comment: Could we see how you defined you 2 relations? Also, what exactly are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: And 1 easy way to get your Object2 is `$item = $this->Item()` if your relation is defined `Item => Object2`

Comment: the problem was that I'm using a inline grid on Object1. So it seems if you edit smthg. in the inline grid, the first save doesn't save object1. if you click on the save button a second time, than it works..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you want to get and manipulate the Object2 record that is related via the has_one relationship to your Object1 record. Assuming you have declared your relationship in Object2 like this:

```
class Object2 extends DataObject{
  private static $has_one = array(
    'Object1' => 'Object1'
  );
  ...
```

Your onAfterWrite code in Object1 should look like

```
public function onAfterWrite(){
    parent::onAfterWrite();
    // use the find() method to look up the relation
    $item = Object2::get()->find('Object1ID', $this->ItemID);
    // check that the related item exists before editing
    if($item){
      $item->Title = 'test123';
      $item->write();
    }
}
```

Comment: that doesn't solve my problem, but it solves this question ;) I found out that the inline grid I'm using on object1 makes some problems.